# keep data in one class to pass to every activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

i have a data that i got from json. and i need that data to every activity in my project. if i pass it using `getExtra` with intent when i back to other activity the data may lost. so i want to make a class that can keep the data so i can call it in every activity when i need it. is it possible? if yes how?

this is my example code when i call json. and maybe i think i want to make this call function to another class so i can call the data in every activity

```
try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://example.com/user")
                    .get()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                    .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                    .addHeader("Postman-Token", "e03845a5-dcb4-4835-9a9a-e9574fb5ed73")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            Log.d("respon after token", "" + response);
            Log.d("json", "" + response.body().string());
            String jsonData = response.body().string();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            token = object.getString("id");
            token = object.getString("name");
            token = object.getString("username");
            token = object.getString("email");
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Use SharedPreferences for all activity used.

Comment: You can use Shared Preference for storing and using the same data in different different activity :-  see this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23024962/2919483

Comment: am i have to make another one class to use it or just in that activity?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [shared-preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java) for same.

Comment: is must be in another class?

Comment: yes you need to create another class for shared-preferences

Comment: is shared preferences can keep the data although i close the app?